# Spotlight search of iCloud folder on Catalina is slow - is this normal? What can I do to improve?

Tags: icloud, spotlight, search

Here are the details of my issue:

1. Since I'm in an all-Apple ecosystem, I've switched to using the iCloud folders as my "general" sync tool (vs FreeFileSync, which I pay the premium for and use when copying to my pocket SSDs).
2. Over time, as I grew this content to include all my "live" client folders, I regularly use the "Remove Download" and "Download Now" options to control the amount of iCloud synced data on my various machines (iMac Pro, iMac, 13" and 15" MacBook Pro models) at any given time to save space, especially on the smaller hard drive (256 GB) 13" model.
3. Sometimes I need to find a file quickly, and I've taken to using the [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) app since Spotlight (frequently) will locate files -- at all.

Questions:

- Is this a bug or a "feature"?
- If this is a known issue (at least in Catalina), is there a workaround other than using another tool like EasyFind?

Comment: Easy find will open all files so will download them. I suspect spotlight is the only tool that is iCloud aware.